# タイムラインへのリンクを表示して欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了

ある質問についてのタイムラインは、以下の様なURLで確認できることを先ほど知りました。

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1513/timeline?asc=True

メタの質問&回答へのup/down voteやタグ付けの履歴(タイムライン)は、スタック・オーバーフローへの変更の提案を accept する根拠として機能しています。よってタイムラインに誰もが容易にアクセスできることは、変更の意思決定がどのようになされたかについて、透明性を与える上でとても重要な情報です。

しかしそれにも関わらず、タイムラインにアクセスするためのURLは、質問からのリンクが無いなど明確ではありません。よって質問のページ内にタイムラインへアクセスする導線を追加することで、それを明確にするよう要望いたします。タイムラインの存在が明確になるのであれば、そのほかの方法でも構いません。

なおこれはメタに対する要望であって、本体に対する要望ではありません。

Comment: [jmacさんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1592/19110)が投稿されたあと、MSEでの投稿は [meta-tag:status-declined] から [meta-tag:status-deferred] に変更されたようです。Stack Exchange社に確認をとったところこの状況は現在も変わってないようなので、[meta-tag:却下] タグがついていたこの質問も [meta-tag:延期] に切り替えました。

Comment: 更に事情が進み [完了] となりました https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3223/19110

Answer (score 5):

この提案は 2015 年当時一度却下されましたが、その後 [Meta Stack Exchange での議論](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/341401)が進み、2020 年の今日、**全てのユーザーに対して** タイムラインのページへ遷移するボタンが表示されるようになりました。

> [image]

より詳しくは[こちらの回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/341401)をご覧ください（英語）。

Answer (score 2):

質問の番号をわかったら、手動的に`http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/○○○/timeline`を入力できます。

それは面倒なら、[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)のユーザースクリプトでいつもリンクを表示するようにもできます：

https://stackapps.com/questions/4148/view-post-timeline

ネットワーク全体のメタですでに[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)になっています：

[Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post/)