# クリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンス 3.0 vs 4.0 問題の解決策が出ました

Tags: 討議, ライセンス

以前、スタック・オーバーフローではサイトのライセンスが CC BY-SA 3.0 から CC BY-SA 4.0 に更新されたと[アナウンスがありました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3080/19110)。しかし「3.0 として投稿されていた過去のコンテンツを Stack Exchange 社が勝手に 4.0 へライセンスしなおせるの？」という疑問が残っており、議論となっていました。

2020 年 3 月 3 日、Meta Stack Exchange に [An Update On Creative Commons Licensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344491/341401) という記事が投稿されました。これによると 3.0 vs 4.0 問題に対処するため、次のような複合ライセンスにするようです。

- 2018 年 5 月 2 日 (UTC) 以前に投稿されたコンテンツは CC BY-SA 3.0 のもと配布する。
- 2018 年 5 月 2 日 (UTC) その日、またはそれ以降に投稿されたコンテンツは CC BY-SA 4.0 のもと配布する。

2018 年 5 月 2 日というのは利用規約上 4.0 に更新された日とのことです。

細かい情報や更なる Q&A などは元の投稿をご覧ください。

また、もしこの予定された変更に伴って何かしら問題があったり、この変更後に翻訳等で問題が生じれば、このメタ投稿に回答の形でお知らせいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 4):

補足として、 CC-BY-SA 3.0 で投稿されたポストは、それに対して2018/05/02 以降に編集を加えたとしても、依然 3.0 でありつづけるそうです。

Answer (score 3):

ヘルプページ「投稿した内容のライセンスは？」の英語版が更新されていたので、追従するのが良さそうです。

### 変更前

Stack Exchange [サービス利用規約](http://stackexchange.com/legal) および各ページのフッターに記載されているように、すべてのユーザーによる貢献は Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike でライセンスされています。Stack Exchange の内容を再公開する場合は、[適切な属性が必要です](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)。

投稿した内容の使用方法の詳細については、サービス利用規約およびライセンスの法律文の全文をよくお読みください。

### 変更後（英語）

As noted in the Stack Exchange [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) and in the footer of every page, all publicly accessible user contributions are licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license as follows:

- Content contributed before 2011-04-08 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).
- Content contributed from 2011-04-08 up to but not including 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).
- Content contributed on or after 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

The license applicable for each Question and Answer revision is available on the [post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316). See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates) for more information.

Please read the terms of service and the full legal text of the license carefully for more details on how your content can be used and for how you can use publicly accessible content contributed to the site by other users.

### 変更後（日本語）

Stack Exchange における [利用規約](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) とすべてのページのフッタに記載されているように、一般にアクセス可能なユーザーによる投稿はすべて [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) ライセンスに基づいて次のようにライセンスされます:

- 2011-04-08 (UTC) より前に投稿されたコンテンツは、[CC BY-SA 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) の条件に基づいて配布されます。
- 2011-04-08 から 2018-05-02 (UTC) の間に提供されたコンテンツは、[CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) の条件に基づいて配布されます。
- 2018-05-02 (UTC) 以降に投稿されたコンテンツは、[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) の条件に基づいて配布されます。

質問と回答の各改訂に適用されるライセンスについては、[投稿のタイムライン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3223) から確認できます。詳細については [MSE での投稿 (英文)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347758) を参照してください。

コンテンツの使用方法、および他のユーザーがサイトに投稿した公的にアクセス可能なコンテンツを使用する方法の詳細については、利用規約とライセンスの法的全文を注意深くお読みください。

Comment: [help/licensing](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)をアップデートいたしました